# I want to pass productid in my url so as to display details of only a specific product

Tags: django

this is how my django code looks like

```
<a href="{% url 'product-details' product.id %}">Details</a>
```

this is how my urls look like

```
path('product/<int:id>/, views.product-details, name='product-details')
```

after clicking on the link am getting this error

```
noReverseMatch at /products/
```

what could be the problem with my code

Comment: Can you show the url pattern that is like this: `products/`? Also show its view and template. Also `views.product-details` what is this? identifiers **cannot** have `-` in them that is an invalid identifier, do you not get an error there or is this some mistake while posting the question?

Comment: it was an error when I was posting the question but i have used an underscore . You mean I post the whole views and urls files?

Comment: Not the whole views and urls **NO**. Your question is supposed to have a [mre] (stressing on minimal here, also reproducible as currently you don't give enough info), share the url pattern which is like `path('products/, ...)` the view it refers to and the template it renders.

Comment: I have already shared the template and url .The view looks like this  `def product_details(request, id): product = Products.objects.get(id=id) return render(request, 'product-details.html' , {'product':product})`